# Wildfly startup: how to ignore errors and load anyway?

Tags: maven, error-handling, server, wildfly, startup

I am starting this server

```
<groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2.Final</version>
```

I receive some errors related to not correct standalone.xml, like this

```
13:49:13,529 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.server@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:399)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module com.redhat.gss.redhat-access-plugin
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.load(DeferredExtensionContext.java:95)
    at org.jboss.as.server@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_Legacy.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml_Legacy.java:431)
    at org.jboss.as.server@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_Legacy.readElement(StandaloneXml_Legacy.java:139)
    at org.jboss.as.server@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.server@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:52)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper@1.4.0.Final//org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper@1.4.0.Final//org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.load(DeferredExtensionContext.java:90)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.loadModule(DeferredExtensionContext.java:123)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext$1.call(DeferredExtensionContext.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext$1.call(DeferredExtensionContext.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.redhat.gss.redhat-access-plugin
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:301)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:287)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.loadModule(DeferredExtensionContext.java:106)
    ... 9 more
```

is it possible to make server ignore this and similar errors, and load anyway? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using JBoss EAP? The error is telling you the module `com.redhat.gss.redhat-access-plugin` cannot be found. You'd want to look for what is adding that module or has a dependency on it.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins thanks, but this is not what the question is about.

Comment: With motivations, you greatly improve the chance that you get an answer. Furthermore, people may help you solve your original problem.

Comment: You cannot boot the server if you've got an invalid module it attempts to load. There is no way around that other than fixing the module issue. I've described what you need to do here https://stackoverflow.com/q/77272873/152794.